# Insufficient fund validate

Tags: php, validation

Can someone help me on this code i am validating an amount in user account.

My code

```
    <?php


$db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
$select = mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 


if ($_POST['submit']) {
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN ".$full." < [balance] THEN 'sufficient funds'
 WHEN ".$full." > [balance] THEN 'insufficient funds'
END AS 'result', [balance]
 FROM transfers";

    header("Location: transferred.php");
    exit;
    }

?>
```

I know this is only validating the amount entered from the form comparing it with the one stored in database, but i want to validate in between the amount if the user entered a higher amount than the one stored in database it will echo insufficient fund, if the user entered a 0 amount it will still echo insufficient fund.

Only between the available amount and lower amount are accepted, higher and 0 are not accepted.

I am a php beginner.

Comment: If this `$result = mysql_query($sql)` is part of your actual code, you're missing a closing semi-colon.

Comment: To answer your question, you can use [`BETWEEN (*click me*)`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between) as a MySQL method and take it straight from DB. You can also use [**Comparison Operators (click me too)**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) as a PHP method.

Comment: Use `BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000";`

Comment: ok i will check that out if is gonna work, also i want to ask i made the (full) a unique and is not empty do i need to empty it and allow the BETWEEN statement do is work?

Comment: oops it didn't is echoing "Insufficient Funds";

Comment: Try this, it should work `WHERE full BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000";` that `=` and variable shouldn't be in there.

Comment: or `WHERE full='".$full."' and full BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000";` or `WHERE full='".$full."' OR full BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000";`

Comment: i try all that already but none work instead it didn't check the amount or validate it, it just proceed without validating the amount

Comment: thanks for helping me to do this, i wish i have a good way to do this to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling by the amount?  How can you be sure you're even getting the correct record?  What you should be doing is pulling the record you need by a unique ID, like a user ID or something.  Then pull the amount from THAT.  Us PHP to write a simple if statement to see if it is >, =, or < whatever was entered.

In response to comment...
Your syntax is still wrong.  if you are trying to see if the FULL is populated and the same, that's one part.  Then you want to see if that also happens to be within a range.
This is what it should look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transfers WHERE full='".$full."' and full BETWEEN 1 AND 1,000,000";
```

If you want to do this same thing but check against a balance, you don't need to match anything.  All you need to do is take the input and compare it to the balance.  So, ignoring your syntax, this is what your statement should look like.

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN ".$full." < [balance] THEN 'sufficient funds'
 WHEN ".$full." > [balance] THEN 'insufficient funds'
END AS 'result', [balance]
 FROM transfers
```

With that, you are checking the input amount for the possible results (add as many as you need), and returning the current balance you just checked against.

Comment: check my edited code, i made the (full) to be unique, but i want to ask if the (full) has to be empty? because am using a BETWEEN MYSQL

Comment: I don't exactly see what you mean.  But I'll edit my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: ok maybe you should check this link

<a href="http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between"> BETWEEN STATEMENT</a>

Comment: i have try it the way you pasted it but is echoing the Insufficient Funds, be remained that the full has a value of 1000000 in the database is not empty

Comment: maybe you don't understand what i mean, i want to echo Insufficient Funds to the user when they try to transfer an amount that is not of their balance either higher of their balance or zero of their balance

Comment: It still seems to me that you are going about this all wrong.  So I edited my answer to show you a totally different method.

Comment: The commas in `1,000,000` will cause problems.

Comment: check my updated question, that's what i did and it didn't work

Comment: please i need this to work i just don't know how to go on from here

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me to do this i wish i have a better way to do this